# Adding line items to cart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, shopping-cart

We are working on a web application which gives option to users to add line items and an option to change the price, quantity and the description.

We somehow managed to get these done and our work is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/75m7e/2067/

Problem illustrated in here: http://i.giphy.com/3o6EhMulFzJPoXzKms.gif

My JAVASCRIPT is below:

```
function CartForm($scope) {
        $scope.searchInfo = [];
    $scope.invoice = {
        items: [{
              product_name: 'x',
              qty: 10,
              description: 'item',
              cost: 9.95
            },
            {
              product_name: 'y',
              qty: 170,
              description: 'item',
              cost: 8
            },
            {
              product_name: 'z',
              qty: 150,
              description: 'item',
              cost: 7
              }],
         selectedItem : []
    };

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem.push({
            qty: null,
            description: null,
            cost: null,
            product: null,
            total: null
        });
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.total = function() {
        var total = 0;
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem.forEach(function(item, index){
            total += item.total;
        })
        return total;
    };

    $scope.calculateTotal = function(selected, index){
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].description = selected.description;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].qty = selected.qty;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].cost = selected.cost;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].product = selected.product;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].total = selected.qty*selected.cost;
    };
}
```

If you check with the said URL, whenever the user changes the quantity, cost, the other rows having the same item product name are also getting changed. Quantity, Cost are unique by row and should not change.

I don't know what mistake I did.

Can anyone help me get this completed, a big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
function CartForm($scope) {
        $scope.searchInfo = [];
    $scope.invoice = {
        items: [{
              product_name: 'x',
              qty: 10,
              description: 'item',
              cost: 9.95
            },
            {
              product_name: 'y',
              qty: 170,
              description: 'item',
              cost: 8
            },
            {
              product_name: 'z',
              qty: 150,
              description: 'item',
              cost: 7
              }],
         selectedItem : []
    };

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem.push({
            qty: null,
            description: null,
            cost: null,
            product: null,
            total: null
        });
    };

    $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem.splice(index, 1);
    };

    $scope.totalFinel = function() {

        //console.log('test');

        var total = 0;
      //  alert(total);
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem.forEach(function(item, index){
            total += item.total;
          alert(item.total);
        })
       // return total;
       $scope.total=total;
    };

    $scope.calculateTotal = function(selected, index){
        $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].description = selected.description;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].qty = selected.qty;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].cost = selected.cost;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].product = selected.product;
      $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].total = selected.qty*selected.cost;
      $scope.totalFinel();  
    };
}
```

Comment: hi only modified "$scope.totalFinel "  name

Comment: one more code add in delete function
  $scope.totalFinel();

b'coz it's update cart total

Comment: Please see here: update jsFiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/KpKaran/40zr2wt6/2/

Comment: please rename your total function name add totalFinel

Comment: Can you please make change in the fiddle, and update, and give me link? I can check then,

Comment: i change this in my local and it's working, remove your code and add my update code

Answer (score 0):

The index of the invoice.selectedItems and selected model conflict with $scope.selected..

See the working Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/75m7e/2069/

rater than passing the index, i updated the code to pass the item from `ng-repeat` and `ng-change` method to use `item` parameter and update it with the `$scope.selected` model

Comment: thanks, please see this, running you code, it is not working, http://i.giphy.com/3o6EhMulFzJPoXzKms.gif

Comment: What happens when the product x is added again, does it take the updated values for product x from $scope.selected model?

Comment: Yes. but I want whenever the user changes the quantity, cost, the other rows having the same item product name should not be changed. Quantity, Cost are unique by row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
function CartForm($scope) {
  $scope.searchInfo = [];
  $scope.total = 0;
  $scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
      product_name: 'x',
      qty: 10,
      description: 'item',
      cost: 9.95
    }, {
      product_name: 'y',
      qty: 170,
      description: 'item',
      cost: 8
    }, {
      product_name: 'z',
      qty: 150,
      description: 'item',
      cost: 7
    }],
    selectedItem: []
  };

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem.push({
      qty: null,
      description: null,
      cost: null,
      product: null,
      total: null
    });
  };

  $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.totalFinel();
  };

  $scope.totalFinel = function() {

    //console.log('test');

    var total = 0;
    //  alert(total);
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem.forEach(function(item, index) {
        total += item.total;
        //alert(item.total);
      })
      // return total;
    $scope.total = total;
  };

  $scope.calculateTotal = function(selected, index) {
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].description = selected.description;
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].qty = selected.qty;
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].cost = selected.cost;
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].product = selected.product;
    $scope.invoice.selectedItem[index].total = selected.qty * selected.cost;
    $scope.totalFinel();
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://d1e24pw9mnwsl8.cloudfront.net/c/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2>Shopping Card Example</h2>
<div ng:app ng:controller="CartForm">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.selectedItem">
      <td>
        <select ng-options="item as item.product_name for item in     invoice.items" ng-model="selected" ng-change="calculateTotal(selected, $index)"></select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" ng:model="selected.description" class="input-small">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" ng:model="selected.qty" ng:required class="input-mini" ng-change="calculateTotal(selected, $index)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" ng:model="selected.cost" ng:required class="input-mini" ng-change="calculateTotal(selected, $index)">
      </td>
      <td>{{invoice.selectedItem[$index].total | currency}}</td>
      <td>
        [<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href ng:click="addItem()" class="btn btn-small">add item</a></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td>{{total | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Whenever the user changes the quantity, cost, the other rows having the same item product name are also getting changed. Quantity, Cost are unique by row and should not change. It is not working with your code :(

Comment: You mean is user add same item two times and updates one row quantity then other rows quantity should not change right?

Comment: **Why you are allowing user to add a single item multiple times when you are giving quantity option?**

Comment: Product 'x' can be available in multiple prices and description. So we go this way.

Comment: Means user can set price for item?

Comment: Here, the term 'user' is a salesperson, he has as option to set the price for the item based on product description and a customer.

Comment: Then there is a set of products and sales person can create as may with the same name but with different price?

Comment: Yes. Same name but with a different price.

Comment: In this case we can give user a option to add a new row and allow user to add product name too;

Comment: This is a client's requirement, and we cannot change it.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/itzmukeshy7/40zr2wt6/3/) is this as per your requirement;